# Shopify Ajax API - /cart/update.js not working to update product quantity

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I'm trying to remove a product from the cart using the [Shopify Ajax API](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#update-cart), but the product isn't getting removed and I get an `Unexpected token: ':'`
 error in the console.

```
$(".slide-cart-remove").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: {id: 0}});
});
```

On the click of the "remove" button, I'm calling the API to update its quantity to 0. The "remove" button's ID is the `variant_id` of the product I'm trying to remove, which is why I'm passing it.

This is how I give it the same ID as the `variant_id`, if it makes any difference:

```
$(productRemove).attr("id", data.items[i].variant_id);
```

Is there something I'm missing in the syntax?

EDIT: As mentioned below, I tried changing the syntax to this:

`jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {quantity: 0, id: varId});`

However, it still doesn't seem to work. (*note that the `varId` variable contains a real variation ID of a product that is in the cart*)

Comment: Updates take a variant ID and a quantity. Provide those and you will magically remove the variant from the cart.

Comment: @DavidLazar I am providing both of those. As mentioned in the post, the `id` variable contains the variant ID of the product I want to remove.

Comment: Unless you edit your post, you are not providing a correct object. Where is your {quantity: 0, id: 123456789} object? 

Your object is not valid: {updates: {id: 0}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Shopify Documentation to figure this one out. Your attempt to POST to the update.js endpoint is failing as your setup is incorrect. See the correct way to call this endpoint here:

https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#update-cart

Comment: I actually copied the syntax for POSTing from that exact documentation and it is almost exactly the same as provided: `jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: {794864053: 5}});` (exact copy and paste from that page), so I'm not sure why you'd think my syntax is incorrect. I did just try it your way and it still did not work: `jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {quantity: 0, id: varId});`. I've updated the post to show that.

Comment: Nuts! I just used their codes with my test shop, and it all worked perfect. I feel for you! Hidden typo or something!

Comment: Figured it out! As per the documentation: *To change the quantity of one line item, you will need to use /cart/change.js instead and provide the 1-based index of the item in the cart*. I used `jQuery.post('/cart/change.js', { line: 1, quantity: 0 });` and it seems to do the trick. Going to mark this as the answer since it really was in the documentation.

Comment: You never specified you were using line item properties. And yes, that does change things. Since a cart can have more then one of the same variant in it, you cannot just send a zero and expect it to be removed, you must provide the line item index value. 

So I think your Eureka moment comes from realizing your question was murky in that detail. All good though... you figured out your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this as well, as I was trying to remove certain items in the cart. Once I added `contentType: 'application/json'` and stringified the data I was posting (ex. `JSON.stringify(data)`) I was successful.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue